# Django REST Framework group by date field in nested model having many to many through relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Django REST Framework group by date field in nested model having many to many through relationship.
Please, I am experiencing challenges implementing group by for my Django Rest Framework (DRF) project. How can I group by date field (schedule_date)?

#### This is my models.py file

```
class AvailableTimeSlotType(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True,default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='api/uploads/available_time_slot_types/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AvailableTimeSlot(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True,default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,null=True)
    time_field = models.TimeField(default=timezone.localtime)
    slot_type = models.ForeignKey(AvailableTimeSlotType,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='api/uploads/available_time_slots/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Doctor(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True,default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='doctor',blank=True,null=True)
    public_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,null=True)
    biography = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='api/uploads/doctors/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='public_name',blank=True,null=True)
    available_timeslots = models.ManyToManyField(AvailableTimeSlot,through="DoctorAvailableTimeSlot",blank=True)
    verification_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    years_of_experience = models.IntegerField(default=1,blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,default=1,blank=True,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.public_name
    
class DoctorAvailableTimeSlot(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True,default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,related_name='doctor_available_timeslots')
    available_timeslot = models.ForeignKey(AvailableTimeSlot, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    schedule_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doctor.public_name +' - '+self.available_timeslot.name
```

#### This is my serializer.py

```
class AvailableTimeSlotTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AvailableTimeSlotType
        fields = ("__all__")

class AvailableTimeSlotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slot_type = AvailableTimeSlotTypeSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = AvailableTimeSlot
        fields = ("__all__")

class DoctorAvailableTimeSlotSerializerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    available_timeslot = AvailableTimeSlotSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = DoctorAvailableTimeSlot
        # fields = ("__all__")
        exclude = ("doctor",)

class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
    user = UserSerializer()
    doctor_available_timeslots = DoctorAvailableTimeSlotSerializerSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ("__all__")
```

#### This is my json response.

```
{"doctor_available_timeslots": [
                {
                    "id": "7bdc5b57-6fd0-430e-b526-7f4697430fda",
                    "available_timeslot": {
                        "id": "569985d5-62e2-4ca2-845b-e919242c3869",
                        "slot_type": {
                            "id": "4f56e64f-f087-44ef-9865-2cc5356a59e6",
                            "name": "Dawn",
                            "image": null,
                            "description": null,
                        },
                        "name": "12:00 AM",
                        "time_field": "00:00:00",
                        "image": null,
                        "description": "",
                        "created_at": "2023-02-23T14:51:39Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-03-14T13:17:05.636795Z"
                    },
                    "schedule_date": "2023-03-16",
                                    }
            ]
}
```

#### This is the expected json response

```
{
    "doctor_available_timeslots": [{
        "2023-03-16": [{
                "id": "7bdc5b57-6fd0-430e-b526-7f4697430fda",
                "available_timeslot": {
                    "id": "569985d5-62e2-4ca2-845b-e919242c3869",
                    "slot_type": {
                        "id": "4f56e64f-f087-44ef-9865-2cc5356a59e6",
                        "name": "Dawn",
                        "image": null,
                        "description": null,
                    },
                    "name": "12:00 AM",
                    "time_field": "00:00:00",
                    "image": null,
                    "description": "",
                }
            }
        ]

    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `DoctorSerializer`, group `DoctorAvailableTimeSlot` instances by `schedule_date` - you can override `to_representation` for a custom output format:

```
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        doctor_available_timeslots = instance.doctor_available_timeslots.all()
        grouped_timeslots = defaultdict(list)

        for timeslot in doctor_available_timeslots:
            timeslot_serializer = DoctorAvailableTimeSlotSerializer(timeslot)
            timeslot_data = slot_serializer.data
            grouped_timeslots[timeslot.schedule_date.isoformat()].append(timeslot_data)

        response['doctor_available_timeslots'] = grouped_timeslots

        return response
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i get it in array format like "doctor_available_timeslots": [] and not "doctor_available_timeslots": {}

Comment: @TEX use `grouped_timeslots` as a list, instead of a dict. [That aspect is Python-specific.](https://www.scaler.com/topics/difference-between-list-and-dictionary-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you once again.
Is it possible i can get something like below?

{
    "schedule_date":"2023-03-16",
    "available_timeslots": [ {
                "id": "7bdc5b57-6fd0-430e-b526-7f4697430fda",
                "available_timeslot": {
                    "id": "569985d5-62e2-4ca2-845b-e919242c3869",
                    "name": "12:00 AM",
                    "time_field": "00:00:00",
                    "image": null,
                    "description": "",
                }
            }]
}

Comment: @TEX it doesn't look impossible at a first glance, but honestly, you should put some effort into your own code. What you're asking here is very basic data structure manipulation. In fact, there might be other, more useful questions here on this site for that.

Comment: Thank you. It worked in javascript frontend but i had issues adapting it to work with flutter.
Flutter needed a data model and i couldn't find any solution except the proposed one.

`{ "schedule_date":"2023-03-16", "available_timeslots": [ { "id": "7bdc5b57-6fd0-430e-b526-7f4697430fda", "available_timeslot": { "id": "569985d5-62e2-4ca2-845b-e919242c3869", "name": "12:00 AM", "time_field": "00:00:00", "image": null, "description": "", } }] }`

However, thank you for the help. I am very grateful.

Comment: @TEX Flutter is a UI tool, and is out of scope for a Django question. Good luck though!

Comment: Sure the code below is not working for  me.

`final_slots = defaultdict(list)
        for key,value in grouped_timeslots.items():
           final_slots[{"schedule_date": key}].append({
                "available_timeslots":value
           })
        response['doctor_available_timeslots'] = final_slots
`

Comment: I finally got it "working" with the code below.

`final_slots = []
        for key,value in grouped_timeslots.items():
           final_slots.append({
               "schedule_date": key,
                "available_timeslots":value
           })
        response['doctor_available_timeslots'] = final_slots
`